# Django - static files are not found in root static folder, but settings point to it

Tags: django

I'm starting to configure my first Django project and I find this issue which is really bothering me.
I have set a root static folder to put some css files for my base template there, but Django is not finding any css files there.

My `settings.py` are like this:

```py
...
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'sales' / 'static'
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
...
```

...
And in my `urls.py` I have:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('sales.urls', namespace='sales')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT, show_indexes=True)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, show_indexes=True)
...
```

If a run `findstatic` I get the following:

```sh
$ python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 static
No matching file found for 'static'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /home/dancab/git/django-3-course/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /home/dancab/git/django-3-course/src/sales/static
```

And also, in the browser, I can see the list of files in the MEDIA folder, but I can't see the STATIC folder, I get the following error:

[image: Error when trying to get file list in STATIC folder]

I don't understand why I Django finds the MEDIA folder and not the STATIC folder.

Thanks in advance to anyone that gives me a hint on why this happens.

Comment: I made a typo, you can see clearly that it says SATICFILES... instead of STATICFILES..., so I'll delete this post tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

before the line `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, set `static root` like

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'project_folder/static') # if not works, set actual path
]
```

don't forget to place your project folder name.

Then run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then you can **load static** using **jinja expression** in your `html` files like

```
{% load static %}
```

Then you can link your **static css** files in **root->static->css** folder like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/your.css' %}">
```

Comment: Actually, STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS variables don't belong together in the same configuration. The former is meant for production and the latter for development. My error was a good ol' typo.